# WCF Service Help page for net.tcp binding

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, net.tcp

Is it possible to configure a WCF service (with net.tcp bindings) in such a way that it can display a help page as it shows in case of http bindings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a mex endpoint to your service

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
```

Then add httpGetEnabled to the service's metadata

```
<serviceBehaviors>
  <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
   <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
  </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

Then you should be able to browse the mex endpoint's url with http

EDIT: changed binding to mexHttpBinding instead of mexTcpBinding

Comment: but that too didn't displayed the help page (which enlists all the operation contracts).

Like, if http://localhost:8080/Service.svc is url for service,
then hit on http://localhost:8080/Service.svc/help is throwing the error "resource not found"

Comment: the suffix of the url is not help, but mex, as specified in the endpoint address

Comment: hit on localhost:8080/Service.svc/mex?wsdl also throws "The resource cannot be found."

Comment: did you change the binding to mexHttpbinding?

Comment: Yes. After changing the binding to mexHttpBinding no error message is there. But its a blank page. No listing of operation contracts!

Comment: Finally localhost:8080/Service.svc?wsdl is displaying some info in xml format. Thanks Stephane!